# facebook "add a comment" popup won't disappear

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Sometimes the "add a comment" popup (iframe) in facebook's *Like* plug-in doesn't disappear and content behind it isn't accessible. (I'm using Chrome 21 & Firefox 15)

Try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H4c5p/

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you loading the button through the JavaScript SDK? In this case are you referencing to the channel file when calling Fb.init (ie. channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File)? - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ If you're using the plugin directly and still have the issue I advise you to try via the JavaScript SDK (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins), at the bottom of the section: "For example, the Like Button can also be placed on your page by using the XFBML equivalent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can fix that. The error is within Facebook's code and I think you need to [report the bug to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) to get it resolved.

In my Chrome error console, there is a same-origin scripting error between the iframe for the Like Button and the iframe created for the comment box that happens each time I like/unlike. Also, I could reproduce the error consistently with just two Like/Unlike rounds.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=11#channel=f210065bfc&origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net&channel_path=%2FH4c5p%2Fshow%2F%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df397b02538%26 from frame with URL https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df334b6227%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Ffiddle.jshell.net%252Ff210065bfc%26domain%3Dfiddle.jshell.net%26relation%3Dparent.parent&extended_social_context=false&href=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&send=true&show_faces=false&width=200. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
>    -d50SLIrXc3.js:43
>   g.inform -d50SLIrXc3.js:43
>   i.disconnect -d50SLIrXc3.js:44
>   h._handleRequire -d50SLIrXc3.js:67
>   j -d50SLIrXc3.js:19
>   q -d50SLIrXc3.js:19
>   p -d50SLIrXc3.js:19
>   k -d50SLIrXc3.js:19
>   l -d50SLIrXc3.js:19
>   h._handleRequire -d50SLIrXc3.js:67
>   k -d50SLIrXc3.js:67
>   h.handle -d50SLIrXc3.js:67
>   r -d50SLIrXc3.js:23
>   (anonymous function) -d50SLIrXc3.js:23
>   v._handleJSResponse -d50SLIrXc3.js:87
>   v._dispatchResponse -d50SLIrXc3.js:87

Comment: bug reported and fb fixed the problem (apparently... because i can't reproduce it no more) thank u